# Combobox Backcolor with Dropdownlist is possible?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox, backcolor

The items in the combobox do not appear. This is the code I have:

```
    ComboBox1.BackColor = Color.White
    ComboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ComboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    ComboBox1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("LIne 1")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("LIne 2")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("LIne 3")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("LIne 4")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("LIne 5")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("LIne 6")
    ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Items(0)
```

And this is what I see when I execute it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that makes that you don't see any items:

[`ComboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

That is because with that line you tell the Combobox: *Hey, I'm doing the drawing myself*. And from that moment onward the Combobox will raise the event [DrawItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) when it wants to draw something and it is up to you to subscribe to it and handle it. Handling in this case means: Draw something on the given Graphics object in the event.

Here is a simple implementation that does that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem
    Dim Brush = Brushes.Black
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) = DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit Then
        Brush = Brushes.Yellow
    End If
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        Brush = Brushes.SteelBlue
    End If

    Dim Point = New Point(2, e.Index * e.Bounds.Height + 1)

    ' reset 
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(ComboBox1.BackColor),
        New Rectangle(
            Point,
            e.Bounds.Size))
    ' draw content
    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        ComboBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString(),
        ComboBox1.Font,
        Brush,
        Point)
End Sub
```

If you weren't planning on drawing your own items, you can off course remove the DrawMode line ...

Here is the result with my code:

[image: owner drawn combobox]